# PL/PgSQL: RETURNS TABLE output is comma delimited without values

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, plpgsql

The following PL/pgSQl script returns the correct number of rows, but the output is a list of comma separated values in brackets as follows:

(,,) (,,) (,,) (,,) (,,) . . (,,)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Airports_in_Country(countryCode TEXT) 
RETURNS TABLE(gid int, iko text, name text) AS $$
 DECLARE
    cntry_geom cntry02.the_geom%TYPE;       
 BEGIN   
    SELECT the_geom INTO cntry_geom from cntry02 where iso_2digit = $1;

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT gid, iko, name
      FROM airport
     WHERE ST_Within(the_geom, cntry_geom);
 END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT Get_Airports_in_Country('CA');
```

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

It might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_airports_in_country(text)
RETURNS TABLE(gid int, iko text, name text) AS $x$
DECLARE
-- $1 .. countryCode text   -- just one way to comment
   cntry_geom cntry02.the_geom%TYPE;       
BEGIN

cntry_geom := c.the_geom FROM cntry02 c WHERE c.iso_2digit = $1;

RETURN QUERY
SELECT a.gid, a.iko, a.name
  FROM airport a
 WHERE ST_Within(a.the_geom, cntry_geom);

END;
$x$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM get_airports_in_country('CA');
```

#### Major points:

- There is not much use in defining names for IN parameters that you are going to reference by number anyway. Leads to unnecessary naming conflicts. Add a comment instead, in such a case.
- A **naming conflict** is your core problem. As you use the names `gid`, `iko`, `namereuse` as OUT parameters (in the `RETURNS TABLE`..), you have to qualify the identical column names in the function body. -> `a.gid, a.iko, a.name`. PostgreSQL 9.1 is stricter about that stuff and throws errors. Would have helped you, but you run on 8.4.
- No point in using mixed case identifiers in postgres, as long as you don't double quote them. (It's not wrong, though.)
- This is called a *function* or *stored procedure*. The closest thing to a "PL/pgSQl script" would be the "anonymous code block" of a [`DO` statement, introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html).

Comment: Actually with 9.0 there is such a thing as a PL/pgSQL script when using the new `DO` statement ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ah right, that would work, semantically. Although, the proper term would be "anonymous code block". I'll edit to honor your input.

Answer (score 2):

you should to use a different query

```
SELECT * FROM Get_Airports_in_Country('CA');
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I now get a tabular output but with blank columns.

Comment: recheck your query - probably returns zero rows.